# Use XMPP for HTML5

Tags: html, xmpp

I am curious about how xmpp(Extensible Messaging Presence Protocal )works with html5 and javascript.
 
 **how to implement xmpp chat in html5?**

Answer (score 3):

There is some javascript client for XMPP that you can use to implement chat with html. I suggest to use [strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/).